# css3 Slider auto rotate

Tags: css

I have an accordion slider. which is using CSS3 is their a way to make the slider auto rotate with out using jquery but only with pure css3 animations?
[Here is the URL to my site.](http://pep-perspectives.com/734-2/)

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/bXDHE/30/

**HTML**

```
<div class="neat">
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/files/zebrainpastelfield.png"/>
        <img src="http://www.freewarepocketpc.net/wp7/img/image-effecter-free.png"/>
        <img src="http://www.poyraz.gen.tr/wp-content/uploads/images_4781_1.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.neat {
    font-size: 500px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.neat > div {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 4em;
    -webkit-animation: loop 10s infinite;
    -moz-animation: loop 10s infinite;
}

div.neat > div > img {
    width: 1em;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loop {
    0% { left: 0; }
    20% { left: 0; }
    25% { left: -1em; }
    45% { left: -1em; }
    50% { left: -2em; }
    70% { left: -2em; }
    75% { left: -3em; }
    95% { left: -3em; }
}

@-moz-keyframes loop {
    0% { left: 0; }
    20% { left: 0; }
    25% { left: -1em; }
    45% { left: -1em; }
    50% { left: -2em; }
    70% { left: -2em; }
    75% { left: -3em; }
    95% { left: -3em; }
}
```

Comment: works fine in chrome but not in firefox and yes i know i have changed the vendor prefix :) do you know what it could be?